# Can't get point free notation to compile in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pointfree, function-composition

This is working

```
unique :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
unique p xs = 1 == length (filter p xs)
```

But now I want it in the form:

```
unique = (== 1) . length . filter
```

Error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a] -> Bool' with actual type `Bool'
Expected type: b0 -> [a] -> Bool
  Actual type: b0 -> Bool
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `(== 1)'
In the expression: (== 1) . length . filter
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `filter` is a two argument function.  You can get around this using the handy operator

```
(.:) = (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
(.:) = (.) . (.)

-- Important to make it the same precedence as (.)
infixr 9 .:

unique = ((== 1) . length) .: filter
```

---

If you look at the type of `(length .)` in GHCi, you'll get

```
(length .) :: (a -> [b]) -> a -> Int
```

This means that it takes a *single argument function* that returns a list.  If we look at the type of `filter`:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

This can be rewritten to make it "single argument" as

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> ([a] -> [a])
```

And this quite clearly does not line up with `a -> [b]`!  In particular, the compiler can't figure out how to make `([a] -> [a])` be the same as `[b]`, since one is a function on lists, and the other is simply a list.  So this is the source of the type error.

---

Interestingly, the `.:` operator can be generalized to work on functors instead:

```
(.:) :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
(.:) = fmap fmap fmap
-- Since the first `fmap` is for the (->) r functor, you can also write this
-- as (.:) = fmap `fmap` fmap === fmap . fmap
```

What is this good for?  Say you have a `Maybe [[Int]]`, and you wanted the sum of each sublist inside the `Just`, provided it exists:

```
> let myData = Just [[3, 2, 1], [4], [5, 6]]
> sum .: myData
Just [6, 4, 11]
> length .: myData
Just [3, 1, 2]
> sort .: myData
Just [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6]]
```

Or what if you had a `[Maybe Int]`, and you wanted to increment each one:

```
> let myData = [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
> (+1) .: myData
[Just 2,Nothing,Just 4]
```

The possibilities go on and on.  Basically, it lets you map a function inside two nested functors, and this sort of structure crops up pretty often.  If you've ever had a list inside a `Maybe`, or tuples inside a list, or `IO` returning a string, or anything like that, you've come across a situation where you could use `(.:) = fmap fmap fmap`.

Comment: `unique = (== 1) .: length .: filter` is also possible.  On other hand `(== 1) . length .: filter :: (Num ([a] -> Int), Eq ([a] -> Int)) => (a -> Bool) -> Bool` may typecheck but isn't useful.